# Change view of first tab of UITabBarController by passing parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parameters, uitabbarcontroller

How do I pass a parameter to the first tab of UITabBarController so that the view controller displays content depending on the argument? I tried setting the UITabBarController to a custom class and displaying the content there (I assumed it will be reflected in the first tab anyway), but the content just ended up being displayed across all tabs.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you need to use delegats.

For example:

.h file

```
#import ....

@class OtherView;

@protocol OtherViewDelegate

//your methods to pass parameter
-(void)example:(int)i;

@end

@interface OtherView : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<OtherView> delegate; // Don't forget to syntesize

@end
```

.m file

in some method where you have you parameter pass him

```
[delegate example:parameterName]; //in my example it will be some int
```

int you first tab

h. file

```
#import "OtherView.h"

@interface FirstTab : UIViewController <OtherViewDelegate> {

}
```

m.file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   //if it's storyboard view you should use another method
   OtherView *oV = [[OtherView alloc] init];
   oV.delegate = self
}
//just repeat method from delegate
-(void)example:(int)i
{
   NSLog(@"My num: %d", i);
}
```